# Adding listview to a fragment in android app

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am working on a app where I have 4 fragments. Now I want to add listview on the fragments. I have tried various links from google but haven't been able to do it.

My Code for Fragment class:

```
public class ExerciseActivity extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public ExerciseActivity() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
    // number argument value.
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise,container,false);
    //View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainList, container, false);

    ListView LV = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    String List[] = new String[2];
    List[0] = "tst1";
    List[1] ="tst2";
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, List);

    LV.setAdapter(aa);

    return V;
}
}
```

Following is my code for xml of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Whenever I try to run my app I am getting following error:

> 05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kris.fittracker/com.kris.fittracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at com.kris.fittracker.ExerciseActivity.onCreateView(ExerciseActivity.java:31)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
>   05-29 00:11:42.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that:

```
ListView LV = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainList);
```

**getActivity()** context don't know about **mainList**, you need to use proper **View** that contains ListView with that id:

```
ListView LV = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.mainList);
```

and that View I'm talking about is your View named as **V**. Now it should works.

Answer (score 1):

if your listview contain in R.layout.fragment_exercise layout file, change listview mapping to

```
 ListView LV = (ListView)V.findViewById(R.id.mainList);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting a view from the main activity layout..

```
ListView LV = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainList);
```

this.getAcitivity is the main activity..

**solution:**

Use the view you just inflated

```
ListView LV = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.mainList);
```

Answer (score 0):

My full code (listview is declared above as "private ListView listView;")

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.times_listView);
 return v;
 }
```